# check for undefined while iterating array coffee script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am iterating over an array and I am getting `undefined` variable error while iterating in CoffeeScript. I am not very sure how to check for undefined while iterating over an array in CoffeeScript.

Please find my code below.

```
  i=0
  while Program.flatPercentageDiscountByMajorClass.length
    var 
    if typeof Program.flatPercentageDiscountByMajorClass[i].majorClass == 'undefined'  // this line is not working. throwing Undefined error
      FlatPercentageFlag = true
    else
      PdpTableFlag = true
    break  
    i++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking `undefined` element in coffee script you can use ternary operator like this.

```
Flag = if typeof Program.flatPercentageDiscountByMajorClass[i].majorClass != 'undefined' then false else true
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that `Program.flatPercentageDiscountByMajorClass[i]` is `undefined`, and trying to access the `majorClass` property on it raises an error.

You can use the [existential operator](https://coffeescript.org/#existential-operator) in coffeescript to avoid this.

```
if typeof Program.flatPercentageDiscountByMajorClass[i]?.majorClass == 'undefined'  
// The existential operator goes before the dot  ------^
```

---

**Some other observations:**

`var` is not used in coffeescript. I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve with this loop. The `break` means you will only ever execute one iteration - is this just there for debugging purposes?

You should look into [loops & comprehensions](https://coffeescript.org/#loops) for iterating over arrays in coffeescript rather than using a `while` loop.